# Failing to instantiate tiles in Unity 3D simple Endless Runner

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, instantiation

I am completely new to Unity and game dev, so maybe this is a primitive question, but I am stuck in it.

I am trying to make very basic Endless Runner, I have created the player, adjusted the camera, etc. now I have to generate blocks of the floor to make the game "endless".

I have made a prefab, and now I am trying to instantiate it on the place I want to using coordinates, and I am adding +1 to each one for the next possibly generated coordinate, but the code doesn't work. Please help, where is the issue?

```c#
void Update()
{
    Instantiate(block, new Vector3(0, 1.91f, 21.85f), block.rotation);
    if (pos < 200)
    {
        Instantiate(block, new Vector3(1.9f, -5.33f, pos), block.rotation);
        pos += 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working. Do you see any blocks in the editors `Hierarchy`? Are there any errors in the `Console`? 

You are adding +2 to each block in the z direction. The second block will be placed in front of the first block (if pos starts at 0).

Comment: Are you sure you want to instantiate an object **every frame** ?

Comment: @aalmigthy there are the block in the hierarchy, i have assigned them to my script carefully, there are no errors. yes, i want to add+2 to each block to have some amount of blocks until reaching 200 of z. but the code is compiling successfully, no error messages on the console, but blocks are not generating. thanks for your answer

Comment: @derHugo as i want to create runner, i thought i should instantiate every new block

Comment: @anmorik15 you can double-click on hierachy entries to focus them in the `Scene`-tap. Perhaps their position is wrong and you just don't see them in the `Game` tab. Are blocks shown when you drag the praf into the `Hierarchy`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have assigned  the prefab to the `block` property? Also, the rotation of the prefab should already be on the block, so Quaternion.identity normally is enough for rotation.

I think the first instantiate should be in the Start() function, otherwise your start block will get another one on top of the already existing one every frame (so at 1 second in you can have like 60 start blocks all in the same pos (0, 1.91f, 21.85f).

Another problem could be where you have placed the script. 
Are you sure the script is actually on an object in the scene? It happens that you write something and it is not actually added anywhere. If that is the case, just create an empty gameobject and then drag the script on it.

If you have set the script as a component of the prefab, the first block would create an exponential growth of a billion blocks and crash your pc, so dont do that either.

If you have set pos as an int or float and = 0, it should create 100 blocks in like 2-3 seconds and then stop.

Comment: @Kjeli thanks for answer. i have tried it also on Start(), same problem, used Quaternion instead of rotating, again no result

Comment: My last guess then would be that the transform of the prefab makes it invisible to you, if you click on the instantiated prefabs in the hierarchy, is the position and scale what you want? If you double click it it becomes centered in the editor window, can you see them then?